# Import default PL/SQL format settings of SQL Navigator into SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-navigator

I like the default PL/SQL formatting of SQL Navigator but I use SQL Developer to code PL/SQL.

SQL Developers default PL/SQL formatting is not to my liking and I would like to have same formatting in SQ Developer (when ctrl + f7 is pressed) as in SQL Navigator.

Is there a way I can import these settings from SQL Navigator to SQL Developer?

I tried to use "Auto-Detect Formatter Settings" available in SQL Developer to detect format settings in a code previously formatted in SQL Navigator but it doesn't work.

[image]
[image]

In the above Pic, the one in red is my desired PL/SQL format (SQL Navigator) and the one in green is what I currently get from SQL Developer.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this. You do have a lot of control over how your code is formatted, however.

You can also take a look at the [Trivadis' group and their proposed set of PL/SQL formatting rules and accompanying preferences for SQL Developer](https://github.com/Trivadis/plsql-formatter-settings#installation).

[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee and the product manager for SQL Developer.*